# May STL iterator methods throw an exception

Tags: c++, exception, stl

[Destructors may not throw exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130117/throwing-exceptions-out-of-a-destructor) (so [stack unwinding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2331316/what-is-stack-unwinding) can complete during exception handling), and must deallocate any resources allocated to the object (so no resources leak). A design for an object that contains several other objects (or is allocated several resources) might record pointers to them in an STL container. The destructor would therefore use the following iterator-related methods:

- `begin()`, `end()` for the container
- `operator++` for a valid iterator
- `operator*` or `operator->` for a valid iterator

But to guarantee that the destructor both does not throw exceptions and deallocates its resources you would need to rely on those methods never throwing exceptions.

Is it safe to rely on those methods never throwing exceptions? It is hard to imagine a practical implementation that would throw exceptions, as under the hood an STL iterator is essentially a pointer. But does standard C++ **require** that those methods never throw exceptions? I've not found a clear statement in the C++ standard.

---

**Edit**: The interesting case is for C++ 03 when you want to have [a container of *pointers* to resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141337/c-stl-should-i-store-entire-objects-or-pointers-to-objects). There are good reasons for doing this; for example, if you have polymorphic resources. As [Björn Pollex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7902452/may-stl-iterator-methods-throw-an-exception/7902491#7902491) points out in his answer, if you use a container of resources (such as a `std::list< Resource >`) rather than a container of pointers to resources, the destructor of the container will take care of destruction (deallocation) of the `Resource` objects for you.

Comment: "as under the hood an STL iterator is essentially a pointer" - you should never rely on that assumption. The concept is based on pointer, but implementation not necessarily.

Comment: Destructors may throw exceptions, actually... as long as they catch them :). The rule is "an exception can't *propagate out* of a destructor".

Comment: The rule isn't even that, it's "if an exception propagates out of a destructor, the program will `terminate` under certain conditions". And I think it may have UB under certain conditions too, if the destructed object is part of an array and/or container, I can't remember. Whether you consider `terminate` an acceptable demise for your program depends on the program, although obviously if you're writing components that are supposed to be easily re-usable then you'd avoid it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> operator++ for a valid iterator

The C++ standard (I refer to N3290 draft) does not give nothrow guarantee for increment operator of iterators.

For example, `std::istreambuf_iterator::operator++` effects in call to `std::basic_streambuf::sbumpc`. The `sbumpc` may call `uflow` which in turn may throw exception.

Comment: I appreciate MSalters & Raedwald

Comment: This is, however, specified behavior, i.e. it's required that `istreambuf_iterator::operator++` have this effect. But importantly, the operator should not throw an exception if `sbumpc` doesn't. This is generally true - an iterator over a defined range (a container) can't just arbitrarily throw an exception when incremented within that range. Otherwise, an implementation could simply _always_ throw an exception and still satisfy the requirements of the spec.

Answer (score 6):

> no copy constructor or assignment operator of a returned iterator throws an exception

That's from the C++03 standard. I don't think that the standard goes any further than that.

Btw. it's `23.1.10`

Comment: Leaving the increment and dereference operators, and `begin() and `end()`.

Comment: @Raedwald I don't think that the standard requires iterator operations to be non-throwing.

Answer (score 1):

> The destructor would therefore use the following iterator-related
>   methods

No it would not. The destructor of that object would just call the destructor of the container, which would in turn be guaranteed to not throw an exception.

If you use RAII correctly, you will almost never run into a scenario where you have to explicitly release resources. This could be achieved by have the container store `shared_ptr` or `unique_ptr`, or by using something like [Boost.Pointer Container](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_container.html).

Comment: In the case of a `std::vector< Resource >`, yes. But not in the case of `std::vector< Resource * >`.

Comment: @Raedwald: I have extended my answer. This scenario should be cover by using the appropriate classes for resource-management.

Comment: `shared_ptr`, `unique_ptr`, Boost: I'm asking about standard C++ 2003.

Comment: @Raedwald: Depending on which compiler(s) you use, you might have support for TR1. Then you could use `std::tr1::shared_ptr` out of the box.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: You cannot put an `auto_ptr` into a standard container.

Comment: @BjörnPollex: Oops, my bad! Removed comment.

Comment: For the reasons that you may not create STL containers of `std::auto_ptr` see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111478/why-is-it-wrong-to-use-stdauto-ptr-with-stl-containers

Comment: "The destructor of that object would just call the destructor of the container": that implies that the destructor of the container has a means for iterating through the container **without** the danger of throwing an exception. It is hard to imagine how that could be possible without providing a similar guarantee for the provided `<Container>::iterator` class.

Comment: @Raedwald: I don't know how Boost.Pointer Container does it, but they seem to handle it..

Comment: @Raedwald: The Boost `shared_ptr` and `unique_ptr` classes are perfectly legal Standard C++03.

Answer (score 0):

According to http://www.tenouk.com/Module31.html these operations (for '*' and '->' it depends also on the type stored) are no throw for STL containers.