# How do delete items in a vector if using remove_if and items are pointers to objects?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, vector, erase, remove-if

I fear that I am running into memory leak issues by doing the following:

(Sample code)

```
class myItem //random container stuff mostly. All primatives.
{
    int index;
    char* name;
    int val1;
    int val2;
};

class vecList
{

    vector< myitem* > *myVec;

    void delete()
    { 
        MyVec->erase(std::remove_if(myVec->begin(), MyVec->end(), IsMarkedToDelete), MyVec->end()); //leak here?
    }
};
```

Erase doesn't free the memory if it's a pointer, right? If I wasn't using remove_if, I could call delete on the pointer before destroying it. How would I do it in this case? Smart Pointers? I'd prefer not to re-implement everything with them and I don't really want to add the boost library.

Thanks!

Comment: well it depends on how `myitem` was created and what exactly `myitem` contains...

Comment: General C++ advice: If you're using raw pointers, you're doing it wrong. (This isn't absolute, but those who know what they're doing know when to ignore this advice.)

Comment: @Kerrek: With a small `nonowning_ptr` wrapper class, that is essentially a raw pointer but with a descriptive name, you can totally avoid using raw pointers. :)

Comment: @Xeo: Yay. And by the time you do that, you will probably already know how to do something like the OP asks :-)

Comment: Safely destroying objects referenced by an STL container of pointers is tricky because STL iterator operations may throw exceptions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7902452/may-stl-iterator-methods-throw-an-exception

Comment: you don't allocate anything dynamically, no need to worry about deleting stuff... btw, why the pointers ? Can't you just do a `vector<myitem> myVec` and then in the delete function use `.` instead of `->` ?

Comment: Related (but **not** duplicate) question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307082/cleaning-up-an-stl-list-vector-of-pointers

Comment: @KerrekSB, @Xeo, I think "If your raw pointers own the pointee, you're doing it wrong" is more correct.  I don't see `nonowning_ptr` being particularly useful.

Comment: @deft: Yeah, that description would be a better fit. And know what? That's what the `nonowning_ptr` name describes. ;) It's all about expressing your intent.

Comment: @deft_code I'd agree.  It's actually rare in most applications for a pointer to own an object, and most pointers should be raw.  It's only in exceptional cases where a container owns objects, but contains pointers.  (I don't think I've encountered it in over 20 years of C++.)

Comment: @Raedwald: Does that mean that I shouldn't iterate through and call delete and erase() on each item in my destructor?

Comment: @Jordan: I don't know precisely what the constraints on your code are, but if you iterate through the container you should consider the possibility that `iterator::operator++`, `iterator::operator*` or `iterator::operator->` throw an exception.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could just delete the item in your `IsMarkedToDelete` function when it returns true.

Comment: That's actually a good idea. I'll first see if I can just rework the code to not use pointers to items, but if that turns out to be impossible this might be the way to go (assuming there are no problems doing this?)

Answer (score 3):

If the only pointers to the object were in the vector, then you've
leaked memory as soon as you call `remove_if`.  `remove_if` moves the
pointers which you are keeping down, but it doesn't say anything about
the values behind the iterator it returns.  Thus if you have something
like `[a, b, c, d]` (where `a`, `b`, etc. represent different pointers),
then after `e = remove_if( v.begin(), v.end(), matches(b) )`, your
vector might (and probably will) look like `[a, c, d, d]`, with `e`
pointing to the second `d`, and all trace of `b` lost forever.

The obvious solution would be to use `shared_ptr` in the `vector`; this
would ensure that any pointer which ended up removed from the `vector`
would be deleted.  Failing that, you can use two passes: the first would
be a `for_each` with something like:

```
struct DeleteIfCondition
{
    void operator()( ObjectType* &ptr ) const
    {
        if ( condition( *ptr ) ) {
            ObjectType* tmp = ptr;
            ptr = NULL;
            delete tmp;
        }
    }
};

std::for_each( v.begin(), v.end(), DeleteIfCondition() );
```

as the functional object, followed by:

```
v.erase( std::remove( v.begin(), v.end(), NULL ), v.end() );
```

Comment: Your functor is about what I'd use for my answer, just adding the bool return. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `remove_if`, then `for_each` from the return value till the end and then erase. That would, of course, make your code a bit longer. Another possibility is to store `shared_ptr` pointers, if your code agrees with that.

The above is a blunt lie, as Benjamin pointed out, so you're only left with "another possibility".

Comment: How would using for_each help?

Comment: `std::for_each(rif=std::remove_if(...),YourVec->end(),[](myitem* i){delete i;}); std::erase(rif,YourVec->end());` — I spoke c++11 for brevity, you'd have to introduce deleter function in c++, I believe, if you don't have it handy in your project.

Comment: This assumes that remove_if does a swap, moving the removed items to the end.  It makes no such promises.

Comment: So, I'm only left with using shared_ptrs? My code is pretty heavily threaded. Isn't that going to cause some issues?

Comment: I don't know much about your code. The third possibility is to run through your items first to delete and nullify, for instance, items and then remove/erase nulls.

Comment: WOW!!, it ***is*** unspecified.  That blows my mind.  Surely that is an error in the standard.

Comment: deft, it's not. Actually, specifying it would make `remove_if` unnecessarily inefficient. I'd rather say it was my error to assume it.

Comment: `std::partition` is available if you want to partition the sequence.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this function:

```
template<typename T, typename TESTFN>
void delete_if(std::vector<T*>& vec, TESTFN&& predicate)
{
   auto it = remove_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [&](T* item) {
      if (predicate(item)) {
         delete item;
         return true;
      }
      return false;
   });
   vec.erase(it, vec.end());
}
```

Ex:

```
delete_if(MyVec, [](T* item) { return item->index == 5; });
```